# Show $G=\langle\delta\rangle\ltimes D$ is nilpotent of class $2$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, semidirect-product, nilpotent-groups

This is part of **Exercise 5.2.2(a)** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)*". According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3ANilpotent%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24(a_1%2C%20a_2)%5E%5Cdelta%3D(a_1%2C%20a_1a_2)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asemidirect%20product&p=10), it is new to MSE.

It is marked as being referred to later on in the textbook.

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

On page 27 of Robinson's book,

> [S]uppose that we are given two groups $H$ and $N$, together with a homomorphism $\alpha: H\to{\rm Aut}\, N$. The *external semidirect product* $G=H\ltimes_\alpha N$ (or $N\rtimes_\alpha H$) is the set of all pairs $(h,n), h\in H, n\in N$, with the group operation
>
> $$(h_1,n_1)(h_2,n_2)=(h_1h_2,n_1^{h_2^\alpha}n_2).$$

Robinson's definition of the following is equivalent to the one given on [proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Normal_Series):

> Let $G$ be a group whose identity is $e$.
>
> A *normal series* for $G$ is a sequence of normal subgroups of $G$:
>
> $$\{e\}=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\dots\lhd G_n=G,$$
>
> where $G_{i-1}\lhd G_i$ denotes that $G_{i-1}$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G_i$.

On page 122 of Robinson's book,

> **Definition:** A group $G$ is called *nilpotent* if it has a *central series*, that is, a normal series $1=G_0\le G_1\le \dots \le G_n=G$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is contained in the centre of $G/G_i$ for all $i$. The length of a shortest central series of $G$ is the *nilpotent class* of $G$.

### The Question:

> Let $A$ be a nontrivial abelian group and set $D=A\times A$. Define $\delta\in{\rm Aut}\, D$ as follows: $(a_1,a_2)^\delta=(a_1, a_1a_2)$. Let $G$ be the semidirect product $\langle\delta\rangle \ltimes D$.
>
> (a) Prove that $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$.

*[NB: There is more to part (a) than I have shared here.]*

### Thoughts:

Since $A$ is abelian, so is $D$.

---

Let $A=\Bbb Z_2$. Then $D$ is the Klein four group. Also ${\rm Aut}\, D\cong S_3$.

Now:

- $(0,0)^\delta =(0,0)$,
- $(0,1)^\delta=(0,0)$,${}^\dagger$
- $(1,0)^\delta=(1,0)$,
- $(1,1)^\delta=(1,1)$.

I can't see the wood for the trees.

Finding $\langle\delta\rangle$ seems intractable, at least using the naïve calculations above.

Since $\delta$ is nontrivial and ${\rm Aut}\, D\cong \Bbb Z_3\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$ is not cyclic, we have either $\langle \delta\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_3$ or $\langle \delta\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

---

I'm at a loss as to how to do this for arbitrary $A$.

Perhaps calculating $\langle\delta\rangle$ is unnecessary . . . I'm not sure.

---

This question is only a small part of the exercise, so it has me thinking I ought to be able to answer it.

---

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$ I have just realised a couple of weeks later that these calculations are wrong, hence the trouble.

Comment: If $A$ is a $p$-group then the map $\delta$ has order $p$. Hence $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group, hence nilpotent. Now consider the case when $A$ is the direct product of $p_i$-groups $A_i$.

Comment: ...$\delta$ has order $p^n$ if $A$ is a $p$-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that saying that the group $G$ is nilpotent $G$ is equivalent to saying that the sequence of subgroups defined by
$$\gamma_{1}(G) = G, \qquad \gamma_{i+1}(G) = [\gamma_{i}(G), G] \text{, for $i \ge 1$}$$
terminates to $\{1\}$. Here $[H, K] = \langle [h, k] : h \in H, k \in K \rangle$, where $[h, k] = h^{-1} k^{-1} h k$ is the commutator of $h$ and $k$.

Note that the commutator subgroup $\gamma_{2}(G) = [G, G]$ of $G$ is contained in $D$, as $G/D$ is cyclic.

Now consider the commutator
$$
[(a_{1}, a_{2}), \delta]
=
(a_{1}, a_{2})^{-1} (a_{1}, a_{2})^{\delta}
=
(a_{1}^{-1}, a_{2}^{-1}) (a_{1}, a_{1} a_{2})
=
(1, a_{1}).
$$
Therefore
$$
[(a_{1}, a_{2}), \delta, \delta]
=
1.
$$
Please let me know if this keeps you going.

Comment: What you've typed makes sense. Thank you. However, I don't see right away how it helps. Let me think about it for a while, please; I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: @Shaun, I have added a few lines of explanation.

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you, @AndreasCaranti.