# Showing, for $G=\langle\delta\rangle\ltimes(A\times A)$ and abelian $A$, that $Z(G)=G'\cong A$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

This is the second part of **Exercise 5.2.2(a)** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)*". According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clangle%20%5Cdelta%5Crangle%5Cltimes%20D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acentre%2C%20OR%20content%3Aderived%20subgroup%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian&p=10), it is new to MSE.

Here is the previous part:

- [Show $G=\langle\delta\rangle\ltimes D$ is nilpotent of class $2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324565/104041)

The exercise is marked as being referred to later on in the textbook.

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

On page 27 of Robinson's book,

> [S]uppose that we are given two groups $H$ and $N$, together with a homomorphism $\alpha: H\to{\rm Aut}\, N$. The *external semidirect product* $G=H\ltimes_\alpha N$ (or $N\rtimes_\alpha H$) is the set of all pairs $(h,n), h\in H, n\in N$, with the group operation
>
> $$(h_1,n_1)(h_2,n_2)=(h_1h_2,n_1^{h_2^\alpha}n_2).$$

### The Question:

> Let $A$ be a nontrivial abelian group and set $D=A\times A$. Define $\delta\in{\rm Aut}\, D$ as follows: $(a_1,a_2)^\delta=(a_1, a_1a_2)$. Let $G$ be the semidirect product $\langle\delta\rangle \ltimes D$.
>
> (a) Prove that [. . .] $Z(G)=G'\cong A$.

*(Here $Z(G)$ is the centre of $G$ (but Robinson uses the notation $\zeta(G)$) and $G'$ is the derived subgroup of $G$.)*

### Thoughts:

Since $A$ is abelian, so is $D$.

---

Notice that the first thing we need to show is an *equality*, not an isomorphism.

To this end, I could start with

$$Z(G)=\{ g\in G\mid gh=hg,\forall h\in G\}$$

and manipulate it to become

$$G'=\langle [x,y]\in G\mid x,y\in G\rangle,$$

where $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, or *vice versa*.

Another way is to let $g\in Z(G)$ then show $g\in G'$, then *vice versa.*

I'm not sure what to do.

---

Let $A=\Bbb Z_2$. Then $D$ is the Klein four group. Also ${\rm Aut}\, D\cong S_3$.

Now:

- $(0,0)^\delta =(0,0)$,
- $(0,1)^\delta=(0,1)$,
- $(1,0)^\delta=(1,1)$,
- $(1,1)^\delta=(1,0)$.

Thus $\delta^2$ is given by:

- $(0,0)^{\delta^2}=(0,0)$,
- $(0,1)^{\delta^2}=(0,1)$,
- $(1,0)^{\delta^2}=(1,0)$,
- $(1,1)^{\delta^2}=(1,1)$.

That is, $\langle \delta\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_2$.

Hence $G\cong \Bbb Z_2\ltimes (\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)$. Thus $G$ is either $D_4$ or $Q_8$, both of which have commutator and centre isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

---

The second thing we need to show is that $G'\cong A$.

I have no intuition here. If I had to guess what the centre is isomorphic to, I would have said $D$.

---

This is only a small part of the exercise. I think I should be able to answer it myself.

My reading of the book has been disrupted by my formal studies. I need a kick-start.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of the form $(e,a)|\,\, a\in A$ are central and form a group $K$ isomorphic to $A$.  Also $$[\delta,(a,e)]=(a,a)(a,e)^{-1}=(e,a)$$

So we know $K\subseteq Z(G)$ and $K\subseteq G'$.

Also we know $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $$G/K\cong A\times \langle \delta \rangle$$ which is commutative, so $G'\subseteq K$.  We can conclude $K=G'$.

If $\delta^i$ is a non-trivial automorphism of $A\times A$, then we have some $(x,y)\in A\times A$ with $$\delta^i(x,y)\neq (x,y).$$ Then for any $a,b\in A$ we have $(a,b)\delta^i$ does not commute with $(x,y)$.

Thus $Z(G)\subseteq A$ and the only elements of $A$ which commute with $\delta$ lie in $K$.  Thus $Z(G)=K$.

Thus we have proven $Z(G)=G'\cong A$.

Comment: Did you mean "$(a,b)\delta^i$ does not commute with $(x,y)$"?

Comment: @Shaun Thanks - yes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what $(a,b)\delta^i$ is. Please would you explain it?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I get it. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: $(a,b)\in D\subseteq G$, and $\delta\in G$ so we can multiply $(a,b)$ by a power of $\delta$ to get another element of $G$: $(a,b)\delta^i$.

Comment: That's what I understand now. Thank you. I was looking at the elements of $G$ as $(\delta^j, (c,d))$ for $j\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}, c,d\in A$.

Comment: In that case $(a,b)\delta^i$ in my notation is $(e,(a,b))(\delta^i,(e,e))$ in yours.